# Index out of bounds error c#

Tags: c#, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

With my function of return factors of a number, I am getting an error that I should not be.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (int element in Factors(16))
        {
            Console.Write(element.ToString() + ", ");
        }
    }
    static Array Factors(double value)
    {
        int[] factors = new int[] { };
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
        {
            if (value % i == 0)
            {
                factors[counter] = i;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }
```

This is the error that I am getting:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in TestSolver.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: you haven't allocated any space to factors.....

Comment: `factors` is an empty array.  What is there to index in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing an empty array, but then trying to assign values to indexes that don't exist. For this application, you may be better served with a `List<int>`.

```
    var factors = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= (0.5 * value); i++)
        if (value % i == 0)
            factors.Add(i);
    return factors.ToArray(); // returns int[]
```

Comment: Thank you, this make better sense now that I know more about arrays

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int[] factors = new int[] { };
```

creates an array with 0 elements. Arrays in .NET are fixed size so later on when you try to access elements with `factors[counter] = i;`, it fails because no elements have been allocated.

You need to either specify the number of elements when you allocate `factors` (something like `int[] factors = new int[16];`) or use [`List<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a dynamic array (you can use `Add()` to add new elements at the end).

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] factors = new int[] { };
```

is creating an array with no elements in it (zero-size). It doesn't magically expand when you do:

```
factors[0] = 42;
```

To resize arrays, you can use `Array.Resize(ref arrName, newSize)` or choose a collection which *can* resize, such as `List<int>`.

Comment: `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`?  Why?!?

Comment: @Tim, "such as", meaning an _example._ But, since a lot of people prefer the generic classes, I'll change to suit.

Answer (score 0):

One other path you can take if you really don't want to change much of your code is to assign an initial size (say, the maximum number it can have) to the array, and then resize after.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (int element in Factors(16))
        {
            Console.Write(element.ToString() + ", ");
        }
    }
    static Array Factors(double value)
    {
        int[] factors = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(value,0))];
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
        {
            if (value % i == 0)
            {
                factors[counter] = i;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        Array.Resize(ref factors, counter);
        return factors;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is this line:

```
int[] factors = new int[] { };
```

You are creating a new integer array called `factors`, but you are not specifying how many elements this array must contain. Arrays must be declared with a length when you are initializing them in this manner. Therefore when you write...

```
factors[counter] = i;
```

...an exception is thrown because the array length is 0. It cannot contain any elements. `factors[0] = i` is not a valid assignment, because `factors[0]` does not exist.

You could easily use a `List<int>` instead of an array to accomplish this. Elements can be added to lists as needed. After you're done with the list, you can convert it to an array using `ToArray`. Therefore you can modify `Factors` as follows:

```
static Array Factors(double value)
{
    List<int> factors = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= (0.5 * value); i++)
    {
        if (value % 1 == 0)
        {
            factors.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return factors.ToArray();
}
```

Note that `counter` is no longer required.

Comment: Your code will still throw an error.. List<int> factors = new List<int>{}; should be List<int>();

Comment: Or, you can skip the `ToArray` and simply return the `List<T>` and iterate through that.

Comment: @Tim: Of course, but the original method used `int[]` so I didn't assume that was a mistake as well.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't set the size of the array and that causes the error. What you can do as a workaround is to have it on a list and iterate on the parameter that your are passing. You can try something like this.

```
 static Array Factors(double value)
    {
        List<int> factors = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
        {
            if (value % i == 0)
                factors.Add(i);            
        }
        return factors.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason OP needs an array, I don't see the value of `ToArray()`.

Comment: I just used what was given on his code. We can also set it to static List<int> Factors(double value)...